# How to play mp3 file in phonegap app?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I have two ways to play mp3 file in physical iPhone 6 using phonegap app. One is working and the other is not.

The environment I have is the following:

- PC with windows 10
- physical iPhone 6
- phonegap app downloaded from Apple app store

**The first one is using cordova plugin (not working) and the mp3 file is located in the same folder with index.html:**
Javascript:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", statusbarAPI, false);

function statusbarAPI() {

    $(function(){
        var sourceToPlay = "01.mp3";

        function mediaStatus(status){
            $('#Duration').html(  Math.floor( media.getDuration() ) );            
            if(status === 0){
                $('#MediaOutput').html('Sorry no media!');
            }            
            if(status === 1){
                $('#MediaOutput').html('Loading...');
            }            
            if(status === 2){
                $('#MediaOutput').html('Playing...');
            }            
            if(status === 3){
                $('#MediaOutput').html('Paused...');
            }            
            if(status === 4){
                $('#MediaOutput').html('Stopped!');
            }  
        }   

        function mediaError(errorOBJ){
            $('#MediaOutput').html('There was a problem. Error code '+ errorOBJ.code );
        }

        var media = new Media( sourceToPlay, null, mediaError, mediaStatus );   

        $('#mediaPlay').on('touchend',function(){             
            media.play();   //does not play
        });     
    });
}
```

**The second method which does not involve cordova plugin which simply uses html tag  (without any javascript)**
HTML code:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="01.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">  
</audio>
```

Is this related to the phonegap app itself ? (the one which is in Apple app store) can someone give me a solution to play local mp3 for using phonegap that works in iPhone and Android device?

Comment: this should help - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_Media

Comment: it did not help, when I press on the button "Play MP3" I get two error alerts: 1. Media Error 2. {"message":"Cannot use audio file from resource 'sounds/button-1.mp3","code":1}

Comment: You followed the readme instructions? You gotta install the plugin first

Comment: yes they are installed

Comment: All the samples out there are tested on Android device. Can you send the project you tried?